# How to create a mootool tooltip with Ajax response

Tags: ajax, mootools, tooltip

How to create a mootool tooltip with Ajax response.Anybody can please suggest me a tutorial for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you tried so far?

You could do this way btw:

Set inside your `parent` tippable elements a [data-attribute](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) to store the url (needed to retrieve the tooltip by ajax) i.e.:

```
<div class="tippable" data-tipurl="/some/url/">
  when I mouseover here, a tip appears
</div>
```

Then, by js, create and cache the tips i.e.:

```
$$('div.tippable').each(function(tippable){

    tippable.addEvents({

        'mouseenter' : function(){

            if(!this.retrieve('tip')){ //first time, build tip!

                var tip = new Element('div.tip');

                tip.set('load',{/* options */});

                tip.load(this.get('data-tipurl')); //get through ajax 

                tip.inject(this, 'top').setStyles({ //set tip style
                    position : 'absolute'
                    /* etc... */
                });

                this.store('tip', tip); //store it inside the parent

            }else{ // already built, just show it

                this.retrieve('tip').setStyle('display', 'block');
            }
        },

        'mouseleave' : function(){
            var tip = this.retrieve('tip'); //retrieve the tip

            if(tip){ //if it's already built, hide it
               tip.setStyle('display','none'); 
            }

            //otherwise, do nothing
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Note that you can use the MooTools' `Tips` class.

Comment: @Kyathi you're welcome ;) ..@Oskar, it was just the starting point to build an 'ajax tooltip system' ;)